# Subwoofer and surrounds don't work with a VIA2020 sound chipset

Tags: sound, soundcard

I'm new to linux, and Ubuntu 13.04 is the first Linux I try...

This OS is awsome, I love it, but for some reason I have a problem with my sound card.
I am using Asrock's Extreme3 X58 chipset with VIA2020 audio codec on it.
The sounds work right out of installing, also had Ubuntu update all that it needs.

Problem is, that only the front left, rear left, and front center speakes work.
The subwoofer doesn't and neither the right channels for both front or rear.
If I switch to Digital output (instead of analog 5.1 or even stereo) i can hear in the both front channel.

The speakers are fine, and the connections are too. switched form windows 8 and it worked perfect there, so no reason why it shouldn't on Ubuntu.

Tried ALSAMixer and turned all volumes up to the sky, but no good.
Please, let me know how can I fix this, Id'e hate going back to windows.